# How do I use the MongoDB C# driver with a UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, uwp, win-universal-app

So I am trying to build a small interface for a side project. I have a private MongoDB instance and am trying to use UWP as my GUI. My goal was to use the MongoDB C# driver to provide the interface between my app and the server. The problem is the driver is only compatible with .NET Framework 4.5.2 or .NET standard 1.5.

I am having problems selecting a library type to use with my UWP app to interface the two. Any Ideas? If I have to I am even willing to spin off an additional library just to handle the interface of the driver and my model classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've known, [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.4.4) targets **.NET Standard 1.5**. However, for now, the highest version of .NET Standard that Universal Windows Platform supports is **1.4**, which means this package is not compatible with UWP apps. So we can't use MongoDB C# Driver with a UWP app now. For more info, please see [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support).

But a good news is that .NET Standard 2.0 has released and UWP will also support it in the upcoming version (expected to ship later this year). See [Announcing .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/). With .NET Standard 2.0, we should be able to MongoDB C# Driver in UWP apps. And if you want to do a test now, you can join [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) and try with [Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/).

> Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4 Preview brings first class support for developers targeting the Windows Fall Creators Update SDK preview. The Windows Fall Creators Update brings support for [.NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/) to UWP development.

For more info, please see [Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/08/25/visual-studio-2017-version-15-4-preview/) and [UWP & .NET Standard 2.0: A preview is now available!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/)

Comment: Thanks, I actually think I might do that I am already an insider on one of my machines. Can I just install the VS 2017 Preview on my on insider machine?

Comment: @crazywill32 Yes, you can and you will also need to install Windows Insider Preview SDK 16267.